# How are Norse gods of Dark Horse comics related with Marvel comics?

Tags: marvel, asgardians, dark-horse-comics

In *The Mask* franchise of Dark Horse comics, Asgardian mythologies are mentioned. In *Son of the Mask* (2005) movie, I have seen Loki, Odin & have listened about Thor.
How are they related with Odin, Loki & Thor of Marvel comics? Are they same or from different universe? If they are same, can you locate the events of *Son of the Mask* on timeline of *Thor* movie?

Comment: Why would you possibly think they're from the same universe?  If I write a novel in which [Abraham Lincoln](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Lincoln) is a reptilian alien, would you ask whether he's also a [vampire hunter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Lincoln,_Vampire_Hunter_(novel\))?

Comment: @jwodder Yes, I can ask that if I am not familiar of whole canon because there's always a possibility that there's tie-in between the stories.. even if they are from different publishers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**They are not related at all. Consider them beings who share a name, perhaps some behaviors, or historical references but beyond that, each is a unique representation of the Norse mythos and its attendant deities. In recent decades, the Norse mythology has experienced a resurgence in modern media because:**

- Most people only have a passing knowledge of them. This helps them be mysterious and new to readers/viewers.
- The history of the Norse gods is rich with diverse stories, powerful and often capricious entities, just right for storytelling. Odin, Loki and Thor are the most commonly used entities from the Norse mythos.
- Odin, is a dark scholar, inscrutable, berserker, warrior, sage, shaman, trickster, he is just a veritable bag of tricks, as liable to kill you as help you. What fun he is to write about.
- Loki, best known for being a trickster god, willing to do almost anything for his person aggrandizement or entertainment, a liar and a cheat, no trick is too low, and no victim too innocent for his taste.
- Thor is the most well known member of the Norse mythos, with his signature hammer, he is iconic in all the best ways. Not always portrayed as the brightest light, but generally considered a good guy, except when he isn't. Be afraid when he isn't.

**Almost every major comic group has a version of these characters, they are simply too rich and interesting to NOT write about.**

Answer (score 2):

The guy who wrote the mask pitched the idea with marvel first before running them on dark horse comics so assuming this it is indeed intended to be the same loki

Comment: Can you provide a source for your answer, it is very interesting.